# How to divide an integer returned from a function by a double value?

Tags: swift

Given this function:

```
func anInt() -> Int {
  return 5
}
```

This doesn't work:

```
anInt() / Double(2)
>> ERROR: Could not find an overload for '/' that accepts the supplied arguments
```

However this works:

```
5 / Double(2)
>> 2.5
```

Comment: Wow that is indeed weird.  Bug in the language?  It is rather new ;-)

Comment: @HaukurHaf nah, not a bug in the case of `5 / Double(2)` the compiler can infer that the literal `5` is intended to be a double. Similar to doing `let x: Double = 5`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you call `anInt() / Double(2)` the compiler knows you are trying divide an Int by a Double and doesn't allow that, but when you call `5 / Double(2)`, it can infer the type of 5 as a Double since you are dividing it by a Double.

Comment: Nice! Getting used to type inference. So this works: `Double(anInt()) / 2`